# entity manager não definidade problemas com doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-2

Estou com erro no doctrine quando tento gerar entidades ele me lança uma mensagem dizendo

```
 **[InvalidArgumentException]       
     The helper "em" is not defined.**
```

meu arquivo de configuração esta definido desse jeito

```
// bootstrap.php
//vamos configurar a chamada ao Entity Manager, o mais importante do Doctrine
// o Autoload é responsável por carregar as classes sem necessidade de incluí-las previamente
//require_once "/var/www/html/noc/vendor/autoload.php";
// o Doctrine utiliza namespaces em sua estrutura, por isto estes uses
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;

//
$root = "/var/www/html/uan/";
////onde irão ficar as entidades do projeto? Defina o caminho aqui
$entidades = array($root . "models/");
//
$isDevMode = TRUE;
//
////// configurações de conexão. Coloque aqui os seus dados
//$dbParams = array(
//    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
//    'user' => 'root',
//    'password' => 'elone',
//    'dbname' => 'ZAP',
//);
////
//////setando as configurações definidas anteriormente
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode, NULL, NULL, FALSE);
//////criando o Entity Manager com base nas configurações de dev e banco de dados
////$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
//


$applicationMode = "desenvolvimento";


if ($applicationMode == "desenvolvimento") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache;
}

$config = new Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($root . '/' . 'models/');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setProxyDir($root . '/' . 'proxies/');
$config->setProxyNamespace('proxies');

if ($applicationMode == "desenvolvimento") {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
} else {
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
}

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($entidades, $isDevMode, NULL, NULL, FALSE);



$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'elone',
    'dbname' => 'ceafie',
);

$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
$helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
        ));
```

Comment: Qual o comando está a usar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema configurando de novo o doctrine. 
acessei a documentação [neste link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) apenas segui os passos..

Comment: Não adicione "obrigado" como resposta. Em vez disso, vote a favor das respostas que você achar úteis. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/57436)

Comment: @rubStackOverflow o autor da resposta é o mesmo da pergunta. E não tem "obrigado" na resposta, o problema é resposta apenas com link.

Comment: Me equivoquei @DiegoF